# laravel jenssejers drop collection

Tags: laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm trying to figure out, how to delete all elements from the collection or drop the collection? 
I'm using Laravel 4.2 and  "jenssegers/mongodb":"~2.0".

Could you help me with this. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per its docs, "This library extends the original Laravel classes, so it uses exactly the same methods", so the same way you'd do it with any of the other database drivers.

`Model::truncate()` or `Model::query()->delete()` would remove all items. Dropping the collection is done with the Schema class's `Schema::drop('model')`.

Comment: Any hints, on how to delete a single entry? Because `Model::query()->where()->delete()` does nothing.

Comment: @DainisAbols You'd need to get the single entry first - `Model::find(123)->delete()` or come up with a query that's specific enough like `Model::whereEmail('someone@example.com')->delete()`.

Comment: Warning. Truncate will drop the indexes also... Well known bug, still here in the late 2019

Comment: @realtebo Woah. That's a hell of a caveat.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I came here today because of this bug, and appreciated to fine the query()->delete() alternative; dropping index is NOT an alternative if you have scheduled jobs that needs to truncate collection AND  you need your full_text composite weighted index

Comment: unless you realize that Model::truncate() 7x time faster than Model::query()->delete()

Comment: @NikolayShabak Faster isn't the only consideration. The whole site might be slow if you forget to recreate the index, and a truncate resets the autoincrement ID. Important to understand all of the caveats.

Comment: @ceejayoz does the mongo have an autoincrement ID?